# TextView in ListView showing up blank

Tags: android, listview, textview, adapter, baseadapter

I am using a pattern that I have used all over my application to populate a ListView, but this time the TextView in each cell of the ListView are showing up blank.  There are the correct number of cells (I can see by the dividers), but there is no text. Please see my layout XML and the code of my adapter:

The List Item XML, edit_list_item:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"
      android:focusable="true"
      android:id="@+id/list_item_textview"/>

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:id="@+id/list_item_checkbox"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    />


</RelativeLayout>
```

My Adapter class:

```
public class EditGroupObjectListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
public static String LOG_TAG = EditGroupObjectListAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Context context;

private ArrayList<EditBuddy> allEditBuddies;
private List<String> buddiesInGroup;


public EditGrouphObjectListAdapter(Context context, List<String> buddiesInGroup, List<Buddy> allBuddies) {
    this.context = context;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.allEditBuddies = new ArrayList<>();
    this.buddiesInGroup = buddiesInGroup;
    for (Buddy buddy : allBuddies) {
        EditBuddy editBuddy = new EditBuddy(buddy);
        if (this.buddiesInGroup.contains(editBuddy.get_buddy_username())) {
            editBuddy.setIsInBunch(true);
            editBuddy.setIsSelected(true);
        }
        allEditBuddies.add(editBuddy);
    }
}

public ArrayList<EditBuddy> getAllBuddies() {
    return this.allEditBuddies;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return allEditBuddies.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return allEditBuddies.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (mInflater == null)
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_list_item, null);

// Another way of instantiating convertView
//            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
//                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
//            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_bunch_list_item, parent, false);

    EditBuddy editBuddy = (EditBuddy)getItem(position);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Name: " + editBuddy.get_buddy_full_name());
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "UserName: " + editBuddy.get_buddy_username());

    TextView buddyFullNameTextview = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_textview);

    buddyFullNameTextview.setText(editBuddy.get_buddy_full_name());

// Checkbox code omitted

    return convertView;

}
}
```

The print statements before setting the text of the TextView are indeed printing the correct data. I have two buddies in the list, and I can see the spaces for them but no actual text.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you check if text color is not white ? or similar to background of listview

Comment: it looks like no problem, maybe instead of passing "null" to the second argument of "inflate", passing "parent" to it?

Comment: "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" is not necessary in <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
Check that the TextView is visible by setting the background to some color, like this: android:background="#555555"

Comment: Well, I messed around and set the text of the TextView to black, just for kicks - and it actually made the text show up! But I hadn't set the text to any other color (like white, where it obviously wouldn't show up), and the text color for my entire app (defined in themes.xml) is black! So what gives? Is this a bug?

Wow, I hadn't even seen your guys' comments beforehand. What do you think?

Comment: are you calling notifyDataSetChanged on your adapter?

Comment: @spinster, the issue isn't not calling notifyDataSetChanged, because I'm setting the content in my adapter (allEditBuddies). The issue is definitely text color, but I don't know why it's being set initially to white.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in this instance it seems to have been the text color was the same as the background, but there's no reason for that to have been the case.  The Activity inherits the AppTheme, which has a TextColor set to black. The font of the ListView is also smaller than other ListViews in the application - so I'll have to see where the disconnect is, and then update the answer.